# Picasa Web Albums API vs Google Photos Library API

Tags: google-api, picasa, google-photos

I have an app which uses the pretty old **Picasa web albums data API** (https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/). A few days ago (May 2018), Google released the new **Google Photos Library API** (https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started) at Google I/O 2018. As of today (19 May 2018), the following endpoints still work in the Picasa API-

1. List albums of user - https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default
2. List photos in an album- https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/{albumId}

Will the old Picasa web albums data api still be supported in future? If no, is there any date decided as to when these API endpoints will be shutdown?

Comment: It seems like it's not possible to list user albums any longer? Have you found any solution to that problem? Thanks!

Comment: @raRaRa I am still able to list user albums. You can verify that it works here-
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
Just look for `Picasa Web v2` from the list of APIs on this page.

Comment: Seems like it was a temp problem

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the Google API Javascript Library and easy way to achieve this using the following methods:

- Listing Albums: gapi.client.photoslibrary.albumslist
- Listing photos in an album: gapi.client.photoslibrary.mediaItems.search({"resource":{"albumId": }})

I found a migration guide on the Google Photos API homepage which explains this...after I had worked it out :-)